# Address Space Overflow

Tags: c, embedded, 8051, keil

I am experiencing a problem with my code. When I compile the code, I get the error Address Space Overflow. How can I help to solve this. I am using the keil compiler and the AT89C51RD2 MCU, and this are the spaces used up so far -

**Program Size: data=149.0 xdata=594 const=1136 code=8467**.

Could I have possibly used up the entire memory.

The error Statement goes thus:

**Error L107 : Address Space Overflow**

**Space: memory-space** (DATA)

**Segment: segment-name** (Function_name)

**Length : 000004H**

**Description: The specified segment cannot be located at the specified address space.** 
**The segment is ignored.**

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the map file?

Comment: You've got 128 bytes of space in DATA.  149 is a kaboom.  http://www.esacademy.com/en/library/technical-articles-and-documents/8051-programming/8051-memory-configurations-with-c-compilers.html

Comment: @PaulA. To check memory distribution etc. GCC has it (never used keil) but "*have to*" have it as well. The doc for [AT89C51RD2](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc4235.pdf) has the limits.

Comment: -- also look at comments by Mr. Passant below. (and above); looks like they are more on an informative path.

Comment: @Rune just checking the map file, but how can I make use of it to solve the problem, because I have never used it before.

Comment: @Hans: That looks like an answer to me (actually *the* answer) - better posted as one rather than a comment, otherwise someone else may take the credit.

Comment: Thanks all. I followed the link given by Hans  **keil.com/support/docs/1241** , and I got to this http://www.keil.com/forum/13193/. 
What I simply did was to check in those functions that was overflowing, and declare those variable as xdata, based on what I read @ 13193. That solved the problem. Thanks all once again.

Comment: @Rune: typically a map file won't be generated if the linker can't produce the binary.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Yes, there is some logic to that :). However it looked like L107 error did not prevent generation of map files (based on the keil doc). Perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: @Rune: I also can't speak to the specifics of the Keil tools, but what would the map file contain? In order to avoid lying it would have to generate some sort of 'no address' entries for some material, I suppose.  I guess that could be done, but it would seem to be unnecessary and not too useful. But maybe there's something I'm missing.

Comment: @Micheal:  8051 DATA space addresses are 8-bit, so valid addresses can be generated if the overflow is of physical RAM (in this case 128-bytes) rather than the architectural limit of 256-bytes.

Answer (score 0):

A note the references this is  at:
http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1481.htm